# Insert one image into another using convert

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation

I have one image `logo.png` of size `720x720`, I want it to be stretched or squeezed to fit the entire height or width, preserving aspect ratio, centered inside a bounded rectangle `top-left: 32,432` and `bottom-right: 607,919` in another image `background.png` image of size `640x960`.

So for the above example, `logo.png` would be resized to `488x488` and positioned at `top-left: 76,432`.

But I don't want to have to calculate `488x488` or `76,432`, just want to use the `top-left` and `bottom-right` specifiers above, i.e. let ImageMagick figure it out.

Can ImageMagick do something like this? If it can't on its own, is there a scripting solution using `convert` and anything else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hopefully Even Simpler Version**

I think this still produces the same result but is simpler:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Make initial images
convert -size 720x720! gradient:red-yellow -fill white -gravity center -pointsize 72 -annotate 0 "logo" logo.png
convert -size 640x960! gradient:blue-cyan  -fill white -gravity north  -pointsize 72 -annotate 0 "background" background.png

# Specify top-left and bottom-right
tl="32,432"
br="607,919"

# Get x1,y1,x2,y2 - bounding box of inserted image
IFS=, read -r x1 y1 <<< "$tl"
IFS=, read -r x2 y2 <<< "$br"

# Work out width and height 
w=$((x2-x1+1))
h=$((y2-y1+1))

# Resize logo proportionally, then extend canvas with invisible pixels to full size of insertion area and composite onto background
convert background.png \( logo.png -resize ${w}x${h} -background none -gravity center -extent ${w}x${h} \) -gravity northwest -geometry +${x1}+${y1} -composite result.png
```

**Improved Answer**

This is simpler and faster and hopefully the same result:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Make initial images
convert -size 720x720! gradient:red-yellow -fill white -gravity center -pointsize 72 -annotate 0 "logo" logo.png
convert -size 640x960! gradient:blue-cyan  -fill white -gravity north  -pointsize 72 -annotate 0 "background" background.png

# Specify top-left and bottom-right
tl="32,432"
br="607,919"

# Get x1,y1,x2,y2 - bounding box of inserted image
IFS=, read -r x1 y1 <<< "$tl"
IFS=, read -r x2 y2 <<< "$br"

# Work out w and h, and smaller side "s"
w=$((x2-x1+1))
h=$((y2-y1+1))
s=$w
[ $h -lt $w ] && s=$h
echo Smaller side: $s

# Resize logo proportionally, then extend canvas with invisible pixels to full size of insertion area and place on background
convert background.png \( logo.png -resize ${s}x${s} -background none -gravity center -extent ${w}x${h} \) -gravity northwest -geometry +${x1}+${y1} -composite result.png
```

**Original Answer**

I think, from your comments that you want the resized image centred, so I have done that.

Also, there is lots of debug code and I have not yet optimised this until I know I am on the right track, so it can definitely be improved.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Make initial images
convert -size 720x720! gradient:red-yellow -fill white -gravity center -pointsize 72 -annotate 0 "logo" logo.png
convert -size 640x960! gradient:blue-cyan  -fill white -gravity north  -pointsize 72 -annotate 0 "background" background.png

# Specify top-left and bottom-right
tl="32,432"
br="607,919"

# Get x1,y1,x2,y2 - bounding box of inserted image
IFS=, read -r x1 y1 <<< "$tl"
IFS=, read -r x2 y2 <<< "$br"

# Work out w and h, and smaller side "s"
w=$((x2-x1+1))
h=$((y2-y1+1))
s=$w
[ $h -lt $w ] && s=$h
echo Smaller side: $s

# Work out size of resized image
read -r a b < <(convert logo.png -resize ${s}x${s} -format "%w %h" info:)
echo Resized logo: $a x $b

# Work out top-left "x" and "y"
x=$((x1+((w-a)/2)))
y=$((y1+((h-b)/2)))
echo x:$x, y:$y
convert background.png \( logo.png -resize ${s}x${s} +repage \) -geometry +${x}+${y} -composite result.png
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Regarding (76, 432), assuming Y coordinate 432 is obvious, the X coordinate is 32 + [(608 - 32) - 488]/2 = 76 which should center it horizontally.

Comment: Thank you. I adapted your script to use command line arguments, saved me days of work!

Comment: Excellent! I am glad it worked out for you - and thank you for the very generous bonus points. Good luck with your project!